# Spring-Boot-Jersey Setup CORS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I serve my front- and backend from two different servers. Now I am trying to get CORS working on the Spring-Boot-Jersey backend. I tried everything I could find on the internet but nothing seem to work or I am missing something.

My current setup uses a `ContainerResponseFilter`. I tried registering it automatically with `@Provider` and manually in the Jersey configuration.

ContainerResponseFilter

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
                       ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

Maybe it is important but I also used `Spring-Security-oauth2` by adding the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation. Please tell me if you need more of my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by using the CORSFilter displayed in https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class CorsFilter implements Filter {

  void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    if (request.getMethod()!='OPTIONS') {
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
    }
  }

  void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  void destroy() {}

}
```

Comment: Ordered is not indentified...Why?

Comment: @Fencer You may have noticed I copied from the article and what makes you think it isn't Java?

Comment: @KenavR I don't care where you get your information from as long as they are correct.  The needed `imports` would have been just nice in case your source gets invalid. But your code won't compile because it is missing semicolons. So the code may be correct in some programming language I don't know, but not in Java.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed it this way,
First  create a class

```
public class CORSResponseFilter implements   ContainerResponseFilter {
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext  requestContext,ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://abcd.org"); //allows CORS requests only coming from abcd.org
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
    }
}
```

The filter must inherit from the ContainerResponseFilter interface and must be registered as a provider:

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {

        register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
        //other registrations

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the @Provider annotation is supported by Spring. Try replacing the @Provider annotation with Springs @Component and the CORSFilter should extend `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`. This is the Spring way of configuring Filters and this will work for any application server.
You can also configure CORS via the  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, which might be more compact:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("...") // add headers
                    .allowedMethods(".."); // add methods
        }
    };
}
```

Check out [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) guide!